# Check if set of variables are defined & not NULL inside execution environment

Tags: r, scope

In a function, I want to check if variable names exist in the local scope (not looking at parent envs) and if they do, are not NULL. Working example below, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way than the convoluted sapply call I have now:

```
a = 1
f <- function () {
  source(textConnection("b <- 2;c <- NULL"), local = TRUE)
  vars <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
  # a, c & d are missing || NULL in local scope
  # (a is missing as it was defined outside function env)
  # create a logical vector where TRUE means missing/NULL
  missing_vars <- sapply(vars, function(x)
    is.null(get0(x, inherits = FALSE, envir = parent.env(environment()))))
  print(missing_vars)       
  # try to auto-detect appropriate values for missing vars,
  # then call the original function
  # ...      
}
```

**SOLVED** - Example rewritten as per Roland's answer below:

```
a <- 1
g <- function () {
  myenv <- new.env()
  source(textConnection("b <- 2;c <- NULL"), local = myenv)
  vars <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
  missing_vars <- sapply(vars, function(x) is.null(myenv[[x]]))
  print(missing_vars)       
}
```

---

Background:
For a function which takes a long list of arguments (hydrological modeling), I am writing a wrapper which allows the user to define the needed arguments as variables in a simple R script. This "config" script is then sourced into the function env. If some variables are missing or set to NULL, I have some code to auto-detect the values before calling the original function.

Comment: You should never rely on scoping. Always pass all variables as function arguments. You can then handle missing parameters based on `missing`.

Comment: @Roland Well, the whole point of this particular function is to source variables from an external, user-written R script serving as "config" file (edited example). I am explicitly NOT relying on variables defined in an outer scope, but want to make sure to exclude them from lookup.

Comment: If you import them, you can check if all relevant variables were imported. For instance, you could create an environment, import into that environment (`local = myenv`), and use `ls` to check that everything was imported as it is supposed to be. If your approach allows importing as a list, that would make it even easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this approach:

```
myenv <- new.env()
source(textConnection("a <- 1"), local = myenv)
c("a", "b") %in% ls(myenv)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

This assumes that the sourced script does not assign into environments explicitly.

You can then use these variables as `myenv$a`, which avoids any scoping.

Comment: Thank you! Using the list-like lookup with an explicitly defined env is much, much cleaner than trying to confine `get` to the execution environment.